# Navigating back to search results having clicked on item detail MVC 3 / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search, pagination

I am currently writing a simple MVC 3 application that displays a list of items and allows the user to filter the items (on the same page).  The user can then click on an item and will be redirected to a details page.

The problem I have is that when the user clicks 'back to list' the search criteria is lost and so is the current page (search results are paged).

I am new to MVC and cannot seem to figure out how this should be done.

Controller

```
....
public ActionResult Index(PacketSearch search)
{            
    const int pageSize = 20;

    var allPackets = this.repository.GetAllPackets().Where(p => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.FromIp)) || p.FromIp == search.FromIp);

    var pagedPackets = new PaginatedList<RawPacket>(allPackets, search.Page ?? 0, pageSize);

    search.SearchResults = pagedPackets;

    return View(search);            
}

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var packet = this.repository.GetPacket(id);

    return View(packet);
}
```

Main page

```
....    
@if (Model.SearchResults != null && Model.SearchResults.Count > 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Timestamp
            </th>
            <th>
                From IP
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.TimestampString, "Details", "Packets", new { id = item.Id }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FromIp)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
<br />
@if (Model.SearchResults.HasPreviousPage)
{ 
    @Html.RouteLink("<<<", "Packets", new { page = (Model.SearchResults.PageIndex - 1) }) 
}

Page @(Model.SearchResults.PageIndex + 1) of @Model.SearchResults.TotalPages

@if (Model.SearchResults.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(">>>", "Packets", new { page = (Model.SearchResults.PageIndex + 1) }) 
}
```

Details Page

```
<h2>Packet Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>RawPacket</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Timestamp</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimestampString)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">FromIp</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FromIp)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must persist the input somewhere and the best place is url(because it can be cached and remembered by user).

Define another Action in controller which will do the main job of searching and send the search parameters through a query string to it.